# Interaction issue between MacBook Pro and Xfinity

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireless-router, internet-connection, macbook-pro

I'm experiencing a networking issue that seems to be an interaction issue between my laptop and the network, and I'm not sure how to debug it.

I'm using a MacBook Pro (MBP) laptop running macOS Catalina. It connects to the internet via wifi using a Comcast Xfinity Gateway (an Arris TG3482G).

Every so often, the machine loses connectivity to the internet. It typically reconnects after a few minutes, or if I turn wifi off and on on the laptop.

What's strange is that there doesn't seem to be a problem with my laptop connecting to the gateway, or with the gateway connecting to the internet:

- The laptop never loses connectivity to the gateway (10.0.0.1). If I ping the gateway continuously, I get good ping times even when my laptop can't connect to any other machines on the internet.
- When I lose connectivity, I get timeouts when pinging the first hop after the gateway (172.24.0.1).
- No other machine on my local network suffers this problem. When I start to have the problem with my laptop, if I switch to any other device on my local network, it works just fine connecting to the internet.

I'm not sure what step to take next to troubleshoot the issue. Since I never lose connectivity to the router, it doesn't seem to be an issue with wifi connectivity. Since no other devices on my network have  problems, it doesn't seem to be a problem with the gateway itself being able to connect out to the internet.